# Backstreet Boys songs written by Brian Littrell

Tags: backstreet-boys

What are the Backstreet Boys songs written by [Brian Littrell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Littrell) in the *Millennium* and *In a World Like This* albums?

Comment: If you go to the "Track Listing" section on the Wikipedia pages of the albums, you can see the writers for each song :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(Backstreet_Boys_album)#track_listing ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_World_Like_This#Track_listing

Comment: No probs :) And meta thread : http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/209/reference-lookup-questions/210

Answer (score 6):

Brian Littrell wrote (or co-wrote) Larger Than Life, The One, and Welcome Home (You).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Songs_written_by_Brian_Littrell